# Can I use my sonarqube server for any git repository?

Tags: rest, sonarqube

I am working on a online-school where student projects are decentralized on git repositories.
When a student wishes to correct a project:

- The student must specify his git-repo-url + private key in order to pull it on the correction-server
- Then several tasks are applied on the project (compilation check, output checks).

I'd like to check the code quality and return a feedback for each user. I guess sonarqube would be a good choice since it supports 28+ languages.

I am familiar with sonarqube used with a continous integration, but I can't find in their documentation how to call sonarqube for my use case.
I'd need something like a rest api for requesting a code analysis by giving the git url & its key and get a response with the code quality output.

Would it be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding, between SonarQube Server and SonarQube Scanner, this is already well explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49588950/3708208

So to do an analysis, you actually need to run a SonarQube scanner with some specificaitons, which is pretty well [documented](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/overview/). When you have successfully set up the scanner, you can easily retrieve reports, status, quality gate via REST API.